# Oracle-XMLTYPE : How to update a value

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

I have an Oracle table with a xmltype column that stores XML in the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<View>
    <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="999"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="20"/>
    </ReportValues>
</View>
```

I would like to know how to update the value from 999 to 666 for variable "HR" and also the variable value from "floor" to "SALES"

Answer (score 4):

While the answer of @Анатолий Предеин is definitely correct for 10g and 11g one needs to be aware that `updatexml` has been [deprecated in Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6044).

Since 12cR1 the recommended way to manipulate XML is [XQuery Update Facility](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/). It's not specific for Oracle but a W3C Recommendation implemented many other XML tools too.

Below you'll find a complete example. However I don't go into the details of XQuery but instead point you to the following documentation:

- [XQuery Update for the impatient](http://www.xmlmind.com/tutorials/XQueryUpdate/)
- [Replacing XML Nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB6043) from *Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide*

**Example Setup**

```
create table so61_t(
 id number
,xml xmltype
);

insert into so61_t values(1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<View>
    <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="999"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="20"/>
    </ReportValues>
</View>');

insert into so61_t values(2, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<View>
    <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="998"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="19"/>
    </ReportValues>
</View>');
```

**Modify XML**

```
update so61_t set xml =
xmlquery(
'copy $t := $x modify(
  (for $i in $t/View/ReportValues/SalaryValue[@variable="HR"]/@value
   return replace value of node $i with ''666'')
 ,(for $i in $t/View/ReportValues/SalaryValue[@variable="floor"]/@value
   return replace value of node $i with ''SALES'')
) return $t'
passing xml as "x" returning content
)
where id = 1
;
```

**Results**

```
SQL> col id for 99
SQL> col xml for a78
SQL> select id, xmlserialize(content xml as varchar2(200)) as xml from so61_t;
 ID XML
--- -------------------------------------------------
  1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <View>
      <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="666"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="SALES"/>
      </ReportValues>
    </View>
  2 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <View>
      <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="998"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="19"/>
      </ReportValues>
    </View>

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks you all. I have used one of the solutions provided above.

Answer (score 1):

check UPDATEXML orace function (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm)

```
with xml as ( select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<View>
    <ReportValues>
        <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="999"/>
        <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="20"/>
    </ReportValues>
</View>' xml from dual) 

select updatexml( xmltype.createxml(xml.xml),'/View/ReportValues/SalaryValue[@variable="HR"]/@value','666'  )
  from xml
```

return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
  <View>
    <ReportValues>
      <SalaryValue variable="HR" value="666"/>
      <SalaryValue variable="floor" value="20"/>
    </ReportValues>
  </View>
```

for "floor" variable it may look like this:

```
select updatexml( x,'/View/ReportValues/SalaryValue[@variable="floor"]/@variable','SALES'  ) 
  from (
select updatexml( xmltype.createxml(xml.xml),'/View/ReportValues/SalaryValue[@variable="HR"]/@value','666'  ) x
  from xml )
```