# To update oracle xmltype field value in new table

Tags: oracle, xmltype

My requirement is to get a specific column from Table A & update the values in table B

```
Table A
Id    Value
1001  TestValue1
1002  TestValue2
```

Table B structure is `Id (Varchar), XMLRECORD (XMLTYPE)`

Expected values to be upated as

```
Id         XMLRECORD
TestValue1 <row id="TestValue1"><c1>1001</c1></row>
TestValue2 <row id="TestValue2"><c1>1002</c1></row>
```

Comment: Check `UPDATEXML` function  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle-XMLTYPE : How to update a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388711/oracle-xmltype-how-to-update-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the `string` and pass it into the `INSERT` statement as it will automatically convert it to `xmltype` (If it is correct `xml` string).

```
INSERT INTO B (ID, XMLRECORD)
SELECT VALUE, '<row id="' || VALUE ||'"><c1>' || ID || '</c1></row>' FROM A;
```