# How to display/update data of tags of Oracle SQL in Python?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have a table. Data in the TR_data column is listed as `<Name>blahblahblah><ServerName>Blahblahblah><Path>1111</Path>`.

Right now I have this.

```
print(f"Which transfer type do you want to see? \n (1) - ServerName \n (2) - Path")
choice_type = int(input("Enter transfer type: "))
if choice_type == 1:
   query = "SELECT tr_data FROM blahblahblah.transport WHERE tr_type = '51' AND tr_data LIKE '%<ServerName>%' AND tr_data LIKE '%</ServerName>%'"
        df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
        print(df)
```

This just prints out the entire data out. However, I want it to just print out the tag of  and update whatever it is in the tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What tag are you referring to?

Comment: @SamM 
Here is an example of one of the data from tr_data. 
<SFTP.Outbound><SSH><Servers><ServerName>example</ServerName></Servers><ServerPort>example</ServerPort><Auth><TypeToUse>example</TypeToUse></Auth><Login><Name>example</Name><Password>example</Password></Login><Connection><TimeoutInSeconds>example</TimeoutInSeconds></Connection>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as a side note, the example XML you posted in your comment is invalid, since it's missing `</SSH></SFTP.Outbound>` at the end. I'm going to assume for these examples that it was just a typo.

I think the easiest way to parse/read/update the XML data in your Oracle table using Python is to do all the work on the Python end.

```
... your code ...

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(df.tr_data[0]) # 0 = first row only
sn = root.find("./SSH/Servers/ServerName")
print(f"Server Name: {sn.text}")
sn.text = "example1"  # update the tag text
updatedXml = ET.tostring(root)   # save the XML back to a string

sql = "update blahblahblah.transport set tr_data = :tr_data where tr_type = :tr_type"
connection.execute(sql, tr_type = '51', tr_data=updatedXml)
```

EDIT: For dealing with multiple rows in your DF, you'll want to apply this logic to each row. Creating a new column is probably easiest

```
df["ServerName"] = df.apply(lambda x: ET.fromstring(x.tr_data).find("./SSH/Servers/ServerName").text, axis=1)
```

And to deal with multiple `ServerName`s in each row, you'd need findall() which returns a list

```
df["ServerNames"] = df.apply(lambda x: [sn.text for sn in ET.fromstring(x.tr_data).findall("./SSH/Servers/ServerName")], axis=1)
```

See if those help?

---

You could also do this from the Oracle end, but it's more complicated. You'd need to query the XML using XMLQUERY, XMLTABLE, or the deprecated EXTRACTVALUE, then write it back to the table using [XQuery Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388711/oracle-xmltype-how-to-update-a-value). The SQL queries you'd need to run would look something like this:

```
-- read the value
select tr_type, 
    XMLQUERY('/SFTP.Outbound/SSH/Servers/ServerName/text()' passing xmltype(tr_data) returning content) as x
from transport
where tr_type = :tr_type

-- update the value
update transport set tr_data =
xmlquery(
'copy $t := $x modify(
  (for $i in $t/SFTP.Outbound/SSH/Servers/ServerName
   return replace value of node $i with $s)
) return $t'
passing tr_data as "x", :server_name as "s" returning content
)
where tr_type = :tr_type
```

Comment: I tried following your method, however I get an error saying "BlockManager is not subscriptable". Here is my code. if choice_type == 1:
        print("You have chosen ServerName")

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT tr_data FROM _.transport where tr_type = '51' ")
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(res)
        root = ET.fromstring(df._data[0])
        sn = root.find("./SSH/Servers/ServerName")
        print(f"Server Name: {sn.text}")

Comment: Currently, df prints out all the SFTPInbound data values. There are 20 for example. I want to read and show all the ServerNames for all 20 of those values.

Comment: Your error is from a typo - you have `df._data[0]`, which should be `df.tr_data[0]`. But I also edited the answer to give options for multiple DF rows, and for multiple `<ServerName>` tags in each row

Comment: When I put in df.tr_data[0], I get an error stating AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tr_data'. Did you mean: '_data'?

Comment: I am also using cx_Oracle.

Comment: Oh, I thought your df column was named 'tr_data'. If it's just named the default `0`, you'd do `df[0][0]` or `df.loc[0,0]` instead. `df.iloc[0,0]` would also work even if it has a different name

Comment: Hey Kfinity, you have been very good help. I am trying to add a "ServerName" column, but I am getting this error. TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'cx_Oracle.LOB'
EDIT: Never mind I got it. I updated your code to this.         df["ServerName"] = df.apply(lambda x: ET.fromstring(x.TR_DATA.read()).find("./SSH/Servers/ServerName").text, axis=1)