# Update an XML BLOB column in Oracle SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, blob, oracle19c

I have to update XML values stored in an BLOB column in Oracle Oracle Database 19c using PL/SQL.

I want to update value 122000 to 500 in element `<ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL1>122000</ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL1>`

```
<ns0:WSMBBILLPAYMENTSERVICETTResponse xmlns:ns0="http://sample.com/ESBMBWEBSERVICE" xmlns:ns21="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMESBMBTM" xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/SAMHBILLPAY" xmlns:ns35="http://sample.com/TELLER" xmlns:ns28="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMMBONLINEPAY" xmlns:ns19="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFER" xmlns:ns5="http://sample.com/SAMHBILLPAYPAYBYMOBILE" xmlns:ns34="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERFTSAMESBMOBILESUBFEE" xmlns:ns22="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMESBMBTTEP" xmlns:ns6="http://sample.com/CUSTOMER" xmlns:ns13="http://sample.com/ENQSAMMOBACCTWS" xmlns:ns26="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMESBMOBILETTOA" xmlns:ns1="http://sample.com/ACCOUNT" xmlns:ns9="http://sample.com/ENQSAMESBACCTINQ" xmlns:ns32="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERFTSAMESBMOBILEPITV">
  <Status>
    <transactionId>TT230397M1GC</transactionId>
    <messageId>MOB230391644542177.00</messageId>
    <successIndicator>Success</successIndicator>
    <application>TELLER</application>
  </Status>
  <TELLERType id="DD230397M1GC">
    <ns35:TRANSACTIONCODE>983</ns35:TRANSACTIONCODE>
    <ns35:TELLERID1>2801</ns35:TELLERID1>
    <ns35:DRCRMARKER>CREDIT</ns35:DRCRMARKER>
    <ns35:CURRENCY1>KHR</ns35:CURRENCY1>
    <ns35:CUSTOMER1>166708</ns35:CUSTOMER1>
    <ns35:gACCOUNT1>
      <ns35:mACCOUNT1>
        <ns35:ACCOUNT1>1012448283</ns35:ACCOUNT1>
        <ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL1>122000</ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL1>
        <ns35:sgNARRATIVE1>
          <ns35:NARRATIVE1>
            <ns35:NARRATIVE1>3203738210-SAM000007828</ns35:NARRATIVE1>
          </ns35:NARRATIVE1>
        </ns35:sgNARRATIVE1>
      </ns35:mACCOUNT1>
    </ns35:gACCOUNT1>
    <ns35:VALUEDATE1>20230208</ns35:VALUEDATE1>
    <ns35:EXPOSUREDATE1>20230208</ns35:EXPOSUREDATE1>
    <ns35:CURRMARKET1>10</ns35:CURRMARKET1>
    <ns35:POSTYPE1>TR</ns35:POSTYPE1>
    <ns35:CURRENCY2>KHR</ns35:CURRENCY2>
    <ns35:TELLERID2>2801</ns35:TELLERID2>
    <ns35:ACCOUNT2>KHR1000028010182</ns35:ACCOUNT2>
    <ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL2>122000</ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL2>
    <ns35:NETAMOUNT>122000</ns35:NETAMOUNT>
    <ns35:POSTYPE2>TR</ns35:POSTYPE2>
    <ns35:gNARRATIVE2>
      <ns35:NARRATIVE2>3203738210-SAM000007828</ns35:NARRATIVE2>
    </ns35:gNARRATIVE2>
    <ns35:WAIVECHARGES>NO</ns35:WAIVECHARGES>
    <ns35:gNEWCUSTBAL>
      <ns35:NEWCUSTBAL>10069600</ns35:NEWCUSTBAL>
    </ns35:gNEWCUSTBAL>
    <ns35:AUTHDATE>20230208</ns35:AUTHDATE>
    <ns35:gSTMTNO>
      <ns35:STMTNO>201281644542178.00</ns35:STMTNO>
      <ns35:STMTNO>1-2</ns35:STMTNO>
      <ns35:STMTNO>KH0010001</ns35:STMTNO>
      <ns35:STMTNO>201281644542178.01</ns35:STMTNO>
      <ns35:STMTNO>1-2</ns35:STMTNO>
    </ns35:gSTMTNO>
    <ns35:CURRNO>1</ns35:CURRNO>
    <ns35:gINPUTTER>
      <ns35:INPUTTER>16445_SAM.PHEAROM123_I_INAU_OFS_MOB</ns35:INPUTTER>
    </ns35:gINPUTTER>
    <ns35:gDATETIME>
      <ns35:DATETIME>2302081142</ns35:DATETIME>
      <ns35:DATETIME>2302081142</ns35:DATETIME>
    </ns35:gDATETIME>
    <ns35:AUTHORISER>16445_SAM.PHEAROM123_OFS_MOB</ns35:AUTHORISER>
    <ns35:SAMHBILLPAY>3203738210-ážŸáž»áž áž‡áž¶</ns35:SAMHBILLPAY>
    <ns35:LSAMSUPTYPE>EDC</ns35:LSAMSUPTYPE>
    <ns35:ADDITIONALDATA>áž¢áž‚áŸ’áž‚áž·ážŸáž“áž¸ážáž¶áž€áŸ‚ážœ</ns35:ADDITIONALDATA>
    <ns35:ATUNIQUEID>SAM000007828</ns35:ATUNIQUEID>
  </TELLERType>
</ns0:WSMBBILLPAYMENTSERVICETTResponse>
```

I have searched the previous answer but seem like none of the posted xml has this kind of complex element hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle-XMLTYPE : How to update a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388711/oracle-xmltype-how-to-update-a-value)

Comment: I got this error while trying to execute `Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "XML": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

if the target namespace for `WSMBBILLPAYMENTSERVICETTResponse` tag is `http://sample.com/ESBMBWEBSERVICE` then remove prefix `ns0` from xml `<WSMBBILLPAYMENTSERVICETTResponse xmlns="http://sample.com/ESBMBWEBSERVICE"` else
add prefix as below

```
<ns0:Status>
  <ns0:transactionId>TT230397M1GC</ns0:transactionId>
  <ns0:messageId>MOB230391644542177.00</ns0:messageId>
  <ns0:successIndicator>Success</ns0:successIndicator>
  <ns0:application>TELLER</ns0:application>
</ns0:Status>
<ns0:TELLERType id="DD230397M1GC">
```

considering the target namespace is `http://sample.com/ESBMBWEBSERVICE`, below is the working example

```
declare
  l_out clob;
  l_xml xmltype;
  l_new_value varchar2(10):='500';
begin
  select xmlquery(
    'declare default element namespace "http://sample.com/ESBMBWEBSERVICE";
     declare namespace ns21="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMESBMBTM";
     declare namespace ns3="http://sample.com/SAMHBILLPAY";
     declare namespace ns35="http://sample.com/TELLER";
     declare namespace ns28="http://sample.com/FUNDSTRANSFERSAMMBONLINEPAY";
     copy $tmp := .
     modify replace value of node $tmp/WSMBBILLPAYMENTSERVICETTResponse/TELLERType/ns35:gACCOUNT1/ns35:mACCOUNT1/ns35:AMOUNTLOCAL1 with "'||l_new_value||'"
     return $tmp
    '
    PASSING xmlfile RETURNING CONTENT)
    into l_xml
from
(
    select xmltype(blob_column) as xmlfile from blob_table where <condition>
);
update blob_table
set blob_column=to_blob(l_xml)
where <condition>;
commit;
end;
```